# clarification about how and what printf(); is?

Tags: c, printf

This question was related to c Programming.

```
 /* program starts here.*/
 main()
 {
 float n=792.099976;
 printf("%f",n);      /*output:-792.099976*/
 printf("%5.2f",n);   /*output:-792.10*/
 printf("%6.2f",n);   /*output:-792.10*/
 printf("%6.1f",n);   /*output:- 792.1*/
 printf("%7.1f",n);   /*output:-  792.1*/
 printf("%3.1f",n);   /*output:-792.1*/
 }
 /Program Ends here/
```

Why were this variations occuring?

According to the book which I follow, `("%5.2f",n)` means 5digits with 2 decimal points.

but when I replace '5.2' with '6.2' , why do I get the same answer?

but when I replace '5.2' with '6.1' , why do I get space in front of it?

but when I replace '5.2' with '7.1' , why do I get two spaces in front of it?

but when I replace '5.2' with '3.1' , why do I get the same answer of '5.2'?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxb7Vv5kgAB5VF9PN2hkaVdOY3c/view?usp=sharing

Link was here, I am not able to upload picture because it says I need at least 10 reputation.

Comment: Did you run the program? If you did, please post the output separately.

Comment: It is because the first number specifies field width, not number of digits. `5` was not enough to print your number to 2 dec. places, but `6` was. `7` is more than enough, so it's padded with space(s). When the specified field width is not enough the result is **NOT** truncated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the printf manual page for all the gory details but basically, you are misunderstanding what the first number in the foramt specifier does. This first number is the *minimum* field width (in characters).  If the number being printed is fewer characters than this (not digits, so the decimal point and sign count!), it will be padded with spaces to fill this many charcters.

So when you use '5.2' or '6.2', the number uses 6 characters, so no padding is done.  With '7.2' one space padding character is added.  With '6.1' or '7.1', the number is 5 characters, so one or two spaces of padding are added.